# SKNavigationListener issues with event handling

Tags: android, navigation, gps, skmaps

I am developing an Android application using skobbler/telenav SDK also known as SKMaps. I am currently implementing a simple gps navigation system using SKRouteManager and SKNavigation manager and the corresponding Listeners. So far I have been able to set the destination for my navigation by geocoding postcodes into gps locations using the google api. I also have alternative routes and the onReRoutingStarted() event of the SKNavigationListener is working right. However, I have a problem with onDestinationReached() - it seems like it does not get called when I reach my destination so my navigation does not stop. So if I keep driving and pass the destination point the app starts rerouting me again. Is there an issue with the onDestinationReached() or any special requirements when implementing it?

I thought it should work because it successfully calculates the route in the first place so it should know the destination point and I shouldnt have to specify it in any other way. But the method does not get called by the app when I reach the end of the route.

I have also encountered another issue with the SKNavigationListener events - onUpdateNavigationState(SKNavigationState navigationState). Inside the method I am trying to obtain some of the information the SKNavigationState object should be able to provide me with. The problems are as follows:

1. Eclipse cannot recognise the method getDistanceToDestination() - acts as if it is not defined inside the class SKNavigationState.
2. getCurrentAdviceCurrentStreetName() returns null
3. As far as I understand getCurrentAdviceDistanceToAdvice() should give me the distance to the point where I will receive another advice and getCurrentAdviceDistanceToDestination() should give me the remaining distance to the end point of the route. Both methods are supposed to return the distance in meters but they provide me with some really large numbers (more than a billion) when my route is only 5 kilometers long. Also, sometimes they return 0.
4. The onUpdateNavigationState(SKNavigationState navigation state) is supposed to get called multiple times while following the route and every time provide me with new information about the state of my navigation. It does get called multiple times but when I use the above methods they keep returning the same values (if I restart the application the values change but during a single test they give me the same values).

If anyone has any clue what could be going wrong. It is really confusing because I can successfully get the current speed from the SKNavigationState object using getCurrentSpeed(). But somehow some of the methods seem to not exist and others return values that dont make sense.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but I noticed that you mentioned you used Google APIs to handle geocoding. Just as an FYI, [Google Maps API ToS](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?hl=en) does not allow the use of its APIs to create a navigation app, presumably because it would be in competition with the Google Maps app's own functionality. See section 10.4.c.iii of that document for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was a bug on the 2.0.2 SDK version - it was fixed in vs 2.1.0 (which should be out on the 30'th of June 2014)